# Android studio - error while installing apk because of system app

Tags: android, android-studio, launch

I've run into this situation - I've cloned project from google source code, configured, built was successful, but it can't be uploaded to my phone because I already have newer version of the app, so I tried deleting it, but it's not possible with not rooted device. Any ideas? How could I launch the app ? Should I change project's package name or what? Thank's in advance!

Comment: change package name

Comment: @M.ArslanKhan it really big project, could you share insights or source how to change package name properly, thanks for your time!

Comment: Change applicationId in gradle.Project->App->build .gradle

Comment: Check in manifest for system level permission, it might be stopping to install app on non rooted device

Comment: Changing manifest file helped me solve this, thanks guys!